# Customize Scrollbar button

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, scrollbar

I am able to customize scrollbar which now looks like below
[image]

But, the **scrollbar-button** looks ugly. I am trying to make the buttons looking like below:
[image]
Can anyone please help?
I am using the below css for customizing the scrollbar.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: rgb(224, 224, 224);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    border: 0.05em solid #eeeeee;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: rgb(180, 180, 180);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    background: rgb(117, 117, 117);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    border-style: solid;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
    border-width: 0 7px 14px 7px;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgb(117, 117, 117) transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement:hover {
    border-color: transparent transparent rgb(180, 180, 180) transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
    border-width: 14px 7px 0 7px;
    border-color: rgb(117, 117, 117) transparent transparent transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment:hover {
    border-color: rgb(180, 180, 180) transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrollbar with Custom buttons(both horizontal and vertical bar).....[Have a look](https://codepen.io/khushwantk/pen/PomByxo)

Have to customize these classes like:

```
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    background-position: center 4px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg 
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(121, 255, 
    108)'><polygon points='50,00 0,50 100,50'/></svg>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

```css
.scrollbar
{
 margin-left: 30px;
 float: left;
 height: 300px;
 width: 50px;
 background: #F5F5F5;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.overflow
{
 min-height: 400px;
}

#wrapper
{
 text-align: center;
 width: 500px;
 margin: auto;
}


#stylescroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#stylescroll::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 6px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#stylescroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 background-color: #a6aebb;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="scrollbar" id="stylescroll">
    <div class="overflow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```